# Prevent array from being recreated each time form is submitted

Tags: php, arrays, forms, session

I am attempting to store and display session data from a form in 3 different arrays, which updates the arrays each time the form is submitted. The first time the form is submitted, the array data is displayed correctly, however each time after that it appears to be recreated instead of pushing the new values to the array.

I believe the array is recreated each time the form is submitted, but I don't know how to prevent this. Newbie programmer here so any help is greatly appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<?php session_start(); ?>

<html>
<head>
    <title> Populating Arrays from User </title>
</head>
<body>

<?php   
// Create the three arrays
    $teamsports = $solosports = $favteam = array(); 
// Create variables to hold each value
    $team = $solo = $country = "";
?>
<form method="POST" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
    Team Sport: <input type="text" name="team"><br><br>
    Solo Sport: <input type="text" name="solo"><br><br>
    Fav Team: <select name="country">
        <option value="Canada">Canada</option>
        <option value="Canada">USA</option>
        <option value="England">England</option>
        <option value="Germany">Germany</option>
    </select><br><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Click to submit">
</form>

<?php
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $_SESSION["team"] = $_POST["team"];
    $_SESSION["solo"] = $_POST["solo"];
    $_SESSION["country"] = $_POST["country"];

    array_push($teamsports, $_SESSION["team"]);
    array_push($solosports, $_SESSION["solo"]);
    array_push($favteam, $_SESSION["country"]); 
}
?>

<h2> Results </h2><br>
Team Sports:<?php foreach ($teamsports as $value) {echo $value;}?><br><br>
Solo Sports:<?php foreach ($solosports as $value) {echo $value;}?><br><br>
Fav Teams:<?php foreach ($favteam as $value) {echo $value;}?><br><br>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Josh is correct, the arrays were being overwritten. I believe this may be more along the lines of what you were looking for:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<?php session_start(); ?>

<html>
<head>
    <title> Populating Arrays from User </title>
</head>
<body>

<form method="POST" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
    Team Sport: <input type="text" name="team"><br><br>
    Solo Sport: <input type="text" name="solo"><br><br>
    Fav Team: <select name="country">
        <option value="Canada">Canada</option>
        <option value="Canada">USA</option>
        <option value="England">England</option>
        <option value="Germany">Germany</option>
    </select><br><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Click to submit">
</form>

<?php
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

    $_SESSION["team"][] = $_POST["team"];
    $_SESSION["solo"][] = $_POST["solo"];
    $_SESSION["country"][] = $_POST["country"];
}
?>

<h2> Results </h2><br>
Team Sports:<?php foreach ($_SESSION["team"] as $value) {echo $value;}?><br><br>
Solo Sports:<?php foreach ($_SESSION["solo"] as $value) {echo $value;}?><br><br>
Fav Teams:<?php foreach ($_SESSION["country"] as $value) {echo $value;}?><br><br>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ok I see how that works, thanks so much for the replies. I still have one question: How come you stripped out the code for the created variables at the start? Do you not have to create variables to hold form data, or are they auto-stored in the $_POST array when the form has been submitted? Thanks again guys, greatly appreciated.

Comment: Thanks @JoshKG! @user3798449, yes you're correct, when you submit the form, the $_POST array contains all the form data, so you don't need those extra variables.

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP arrays only exist as long as the page is loaded. When you post a new form, the page is reloaded and blows away the arrays. You'll need to keep that array data in the session.